# Excel VBA- How do I create conditional formatting without duplicates?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Basically I'm trying to make conditional formatting that applies to all sheets in my workbook, since I'm not aware of any way to do this I figured I'd make a VBA script that creates it for each worksheet. It works but will create duplicates if they already had the formatting, is there any way to prevent this? See the image below has multiple copies of the same conditional formatting because I ran the VBA script multiple times, I want to check if conditional formatting with a specific formula exists to prevent this but haven't had any luck finding out how to do this.

Duplicate Conditional Formats:
[image]

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets   
    If ws.Name = "macrotest" Then
        ws.Activate

        Dim myRange As Range
            Set myRange = Range("A1:GJH5000")

        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=AND(Sheet2!$A$1=TRUE, OR(CELL(""col"") - 5 > CELL(""col"",A1), CELL(""col"") + 1 
              <CELL(""col"",A1), CELL(""row"") - 1 > CELL(""row"",A1), CELL(""row"") + 3 
              <CELL(""row"",A1)))"

        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With

        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ModifyAppliesToRange(myRange)
        End With
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

I could just delete any existing conditional formatting using formatconditions.delete but I don't want to delete other conditional formatting. any ideas?

Comment: Just a question on your script. Why have you `Set myRange` but then use `Selection` when working with the Sheet?

Comment: I'm still fairly new with excel and vba and this was a rough draft, I'll have to fix it later when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have set your newly added `FormatCondition` as the priority with `SetFirstPriority` it then becomes `FormatConditions(1)`.

Knowing this you can then use `FormatConditions(1).delete` to delete that condition and the reset will remain.

You can also use the `Select Case` method but this will to Loop through the Range of cells and will take a quite a while to run through every cell in the worksheet.

It can work well for smaller ranges. See code below:

```
Sub SomeSub()

    Dim myCell
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Set Range1 = ws.Range("A1:GJH5000")

    For Each cell In Range1

        'Build your Formaul here
        'First OR Function
        OrFunc1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Or(SomeFormula)
        'Second OR Function
        OrFunc2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Or(SomeOtherFormula)
        'Cells(1,1) reference Cells(RowRef, ColRef)
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = True Then Func = True
        'Your AND Function
        TestFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Func, OrFunc1, OrFunc2)

        If TestFunc = False Then

            With cell.Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End If

    'Put a BreakPoint On Next cell to check that it does what you want
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll test this myself after work, but if the user creates a new conditional format will it change the priority? or does setting it through vba keep it as priority 1?

Comment: When you use the `FormatConditions.Add` it adds a new condition and it is added to the bottom of the list. That is why when you record a Macro it adds the line `Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority`. This makes the newly created condition condition number 1.

Comment: The problem with this is if my conditional format hasn't been created yet then it will delete whatever conditional format was last created by the user. I was hoping for a more flexible approach but I am able to make this work since my script is a toggle effect, I'll make it create the formatting, then once it's turned off just delete it to prevent duplicates. If you know of another approach that it a bit more flexible (this restricts what they can do while it's turned on) then I'm still interested in alternatives but I'll accept your answer as it did lead to a workable solution.

Comment: @FF7Squirrelman just have the `FormatConditions(1).delete` line at the end of your `Sub` just before `End Sub` this way it will be the last line to be executed therefore avoiding the possibility of deleting the wrong one,  It will be tough if the user creates a new `FormatCondition` during their use of the document.Your `ConditionalFormating` is created when you used the line `Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type........`. Would be nice if you could give a specific the `FormatCondition` a name.